# Define a macro that introduces a pair of variables

Tags: c, macros

Can anyone help me in the following question please?

> Define a macro which has the following prototype:
>
> `F(A, B, C, D)`
>
> After using this macro as `F(name, float, a, b)`, you should be able to use the variables `name.a` and `name.b`. Make sure that your implementation is reusable, i.e you can use `F` more than once in the same block.
>
> Also, extend it so that a predefined prefix is added to the variable. That is, if the predefined prefix is `pt`, then after using this macro, you should be able to use
> `pt_name.a`, and `pt_name.b`.

Asked by Citrix

Comment: #define F(A,B,C,D) struct A\
{ B C;\
B D;\
}

Comment: Hello, Citrix, welcome to SO. Please know that tags are for categorising questions, not for signature. I have removed the 'citrix' tag from the question. I recommend you to set yourself an username in your [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1276952/edit).

Comment: Why not try *compiling* your macro definition to see whether it works ? You'll learn a lot more that way.

Comment: @Kos I guess Citrix is the name of company that asked this question.

Comment: Ooops, sorry then :-) But let's keep the tag `Citrix` related to what they actually do, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
#define F(name, type, var1, var2) struct {\
                                     type var1 ;\
                                     type var2 ;\
                                  } name
```

That should work.

Comment: @EitanT: Oh yah... I'll fix that.